# the correct path of text file to be read under "Integeration of Applet in Web Application" in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, jsp, applet, netbeans-7

I created these 2 applications i.e JavaApplet and WebApplication and integrated them using the following link :

[Integrating an Applet in Web Application](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html)

The Applet was running reading the text file correctly which was located at "src/new1.txt" before integration.
But when this **Java Applet** project library was integrated(as shown in the NETBEANS forum link) in WebApplication project(jsp)...then it was unable to read the file but the applet was visible with no error(but was not showing results of file read).

So, where the file should be kept. I would like to mention that I only want this WebApplication project as it's part of the currently running website.
The whole thing is working correctly but after integration it stopped reading the file at "src/new1.txt".
I can't keep the file at another location, it should be under NETBEANS PROJECT location and should read the file even after integration.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to store *text files* in a separate folder under *web pages* folder(like *web pages/TextFiles/new1.txt*).
But for reading the file stored in project ,it is not the matter where your store it but how you reading.Reading as *normal file* or *as a resource*.?
How are you reading your *src/new1.txt* file. If you are going to store it in your project, remember that you then need to access it as a resource i.e.,

```
     getClass().getResource() .
```

With the file stored in your project, you can't just create a 'File' object the normal way.
For more details visit :[How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)
**update**
You need to replace this code

```
 File file = new File(yourclassname.class.getClassLoader().getResource("src\\data.txt").toURI());
 BufferedReader bf2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

with statemnet

```
BufferedReader bf2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\data.txt"));
```

*Note:* replace *yourclassname* with orginal class of yours.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, now I should read text file using getClass().getResource(). I was previously using this: String x = "src\\data.txt"; Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Notepad.exe " + x); and for reading file it was  BufferedReader bf2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\data.txt"));   Now, Please suggest me how should I change it now.

Comment: @Aman Chawla I updated answer please look into it.I hope it help you.Thank you

Comment: thanks for this, it is showing error at class name, I've entered the correct name....is it an error as I'm using Swing

Comment: @Aman Chawla You done correct thing.You need to enter you defined class name in place 'yourclassname'.for example my class name is `TestDemo` then it should be `TestDemo.class.getClassLoader().getResource("src\\data.txt").toURI()`

Comment: no no, I've done what you've said. I've entered the class name correctly, mine was AppletClass1